# Como generar un id dentro de mi archivo json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, id

Tengo un json al cual necesito que almacena reportes por lo que necesito ir contando cada uno de los recortes e irlos guardando dentro de un id. Es decir, el primer reporte será id: 1, el segundo id:2 y asi sucesivamente. Lo intente pero no se guarda de forma incremental sino que se mantiene en uno en cada reporte que genero.

Este es mi json que va a recibir el id:

```
export const addCollectionResult = async (id, nameRow, nameCol, nameVal) => {
  return await addDoc(colRef, {
    idReport: id,
    nombreReport: 'Reporte' + '' + nameRow,
    filas: {
      fila1: {
        campo: nameRow,
        filtro: [],
      },
      fila2: {
        campo: '',
        filtro: []
      }
    },
    columnas: {
      columna1: {
        campo: nameCol,
        filtro: [],
      }
    },
    valores: {
      valor1: {
        campo: nameVal
      }
    }
  });
}
```

y esta es la funcion que tiene el boton que genera el reporte cada vez que doy click, aqui es donde necesito ir incrementando el id, lo estaba haciendo de esta forma pero se mantiene en 1 siempre:

```
let counter = 1;
  const generateReport = async () => {
    const nameRow = row.toString();
    const nameColumn = column.toString();
    const nameValues = values.toString();
     let id = counter++;
     console.log("id", id);
    await addCollectionResult(id, nameRow, nameColumn, nameValues);
  };
```

Comment: Es incongruente lo que haces, has declarado como constante una variable destinada a cambiar: `const id = counter++;` declárala como `let` o `var`, pero nunca como `const`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Agregue un comentario de como lo solucione, pero no logro que se mantenga el ultimo digito agegado al conteo, si me puedes ayudar alli, me das una idea como hacerlo, te los agradezco!

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre hacer asi:

```
const [counterId, setCounterId] = useState(1);

  const reportID = () => {
    setCounterId(counterId + 1);
    return counterId;
  };

  const generateReport = async () => {
    const nameRow = row.toString();
    const nameColumn = column.toString();
    const nameValues = values.toString();
    const resId = reportID();
    await addCollectionResult(resId, nameRow, nameColumn, nameValues);
```

Pero cuando salgo de mi app o cambio de vista el conteo del id vuelve a su estado inicial, como puedo evitar esto? y que se mantenga el ultimo valor asignado para que siga sumando.

@A.Cedano

Comment: Para que se guarde el último valor tienes que hacerlo persistir de algún modo, en una base de datos, o en algún medio de almacenamiento: localStorage u otro.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo estoy guardando en firebase. Pero igual se reinicia a 1 y comienza a contar de nuevo!

Comment: Ya, en ese caso, deber tomar el último valor de Firebase y seguir contando a partir de ahí.